# pigpio library dependencies missing when compiling Radiohead nRF24 library

Tags: c++, pigpio, nrf24l01

I am using Eclipse 2019-06 CDT to compile the Radiohead nRF24L01 library (v1.97) using the pigpio interface (v71) with C++. I get the following errors:

```
rpi/rfs_pizw2/usr/lib/libpigpio.so: undefined reference to `glob@GLIBC_2.27'
rpi/rfs_pizw2/usr/lib/libpigpio.so: undefined reference to `fcntl@GLIBC_2.28'
```

I am using the latest Rasbian Image (2019-09-26) on a pizw, and am using the latest 'tools' (arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf). I have also tried compiling with cross-pi-gcc_9.2.0_pi_0_1 (for Pi 1 and Pi Zero) and I get the same problem.

I have pthread, pigpio, bcm2835, and rt libraries referenced in my project.

any ideas on where to look for a solution would be appreciated.